# Include template displaying a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

What I want to do is include a form from a separate template at the bottom of a given page, lets say; "example.com/listdataandform/".

The form-template "form.html" displays the form as it should when the view is included in the URLConf. So I can view with "example.com/form/"

What I have so far goes something like this:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block title %} page title {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h2>some "scene" data</h2>
<ul>
{% for scene in scenes %}
    <li>{{ scene.scene }} - {{ scene.date }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% include "tasks/form.html"%}

{% endblock %}
```

The code inside "block content" works as it should, since it is defined with it's corresponding view for the url "example.com/listdataandform/".

**{% include "tasks/form.html"%}**: This only displays the submit button from form.html, as expected. I realize by only doing this: {% include "tasks/form.html"%}, the corresponding view method is never executed to provide the "form"-template with data.

Is there any way to this without having to define the view to a specific pattern in urls.py, so that the form can be used without going to the that specified URL..?

So I guess the more general question is; how to include templates and provide them with data generated from a view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For occasions like this, where I have something that needs to be included on every (or almost every) page, I use a custom context processor, which I then add to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py. You can add your form to the context by using this method.

Example:
common.py (this goes in the same folder as settings.py)

```
from myapp.forms import MyForm

def context(request):
    c = {}
    c['myform'] = MyForm()

    return c
```

You can also do any processing required for the form here.

Then add it in your settings.py file:
settings.py

```
.
.
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    '''
    All the processors that are already there
    '''
    "myproject.common.context",
)
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does this help me executing the view for the included template to provide it with form data? How should this be used when including the template?

Using render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form}) works fine when the form is accessed through a URL defined in urls.py, such as example.com/form. I might not grasp the context concept entierly, but I am nut sure your tip would solve the problem =) regards

Comment: @sjiffa: By adding this method to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS it then becomes part of the default / base context and as such is available to ALL templates, meaning you don't need to do anything else at all to include it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

> I realize by only doing this: {% include "tasks/form.html"%}, the corresponding view method is never executed to provide the "form"-template with data.

Indeed. You included a template, and it really means "included" - ie: "execute in the current context". The template knows nothing about your views, not even what a "view" is.

> How does this help me executing the view for the included template to provide it with form data?

It doesn't. A Django "view" is not "a fraction of a template", it's really a request handler, iow a piece of code that takes an HTTP request and returns an HTTP response.

Your have to provide the form to the context one way or another. The possible places are:

- in the view
- in a context processor (if using a RequestContext)
- in a middleware if using a TemplateResponse AND the TemplateResponse has not been rendered yet
- in a custom template tag

In all cases this will just insert the form in your template's context - you'll still have to take care of the form processing when it's posted. There are different ways to address this problem but from what I guess of your use case (adding the same form and processing to a couple differents views of your own app), using a custom TemplateResponse subclass taking care of the form's initialisation and processing might just be the ticket.

Comment: Both your answer and @hellsgate's helped clarify how requests and context work in Django. I also found that the included template inherits the context of the template initializing the include, which can be useful. Just have to change my approach to the design, and it should work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: An example of these cases would add a lot of value